# Retrieve Database Constants

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I want to retrieve database constants through query in front end to fill this constant string in DropDownList.

I have tried following query

```
  select pr_Package.constant_String from dual;
```

Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reference a packaged constant directly in a SQL statement.

You can add a function to your package that returns the constant and call that function from SQL.  Something like this will work (though you may want to consider moving the constant to the package body rather than the package specification once you have a function to return the data).

```
create or replace package pkg_const
as
  some_constant number;
  function get_constant
    return number;
end;

create or replace package body pkg_const
as
  function get_constant
    return number
  is
  begin
    return some_constant;
  end;
end;

select pkg_const.get_constant from dual;
```